# Passing a 2-D Boolean to a function

Tags: c++, pointers, boolean

Why a 2-d address of following boolean "mat" can not be passed like this to a function?

```
void generate(bool arr) {
    ......;
    ......;
}

int main() {
    bool mat[3][3];
    generate(mat);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a boolean. But a 2D boolean array.

Comment: Yeah I was uncertain about the code, but the question title and description seems to ask about passing a 2d array to a function so I figure this should hopefully answer OP's question regardless of their code

Comment: @user4581301, the "mat[3]mat[3]" was a typo. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

***Try following example*** *then attention to bellow descriptions :*

```
const int N = 3;

void generate(bool arr[][N]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            std::cout << std::boolalpha << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    // initialize array
    bool mat[N][N] = { {1, 0, 1},
                     {0, 1, 0},
                     {1, 0, 1} };
    generate(mat);
    return 0;
}
```

The output :

```
true false true
false true false
true false true
```

***Notice :*** *There are 3 ways to pass a 2-d array to a function exactly according ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function?answertab=active#tab-top)) :*

1. The function parameter is a `2-d` array :

   ```
   bool arr[10][10];
   void Func(bool a[][10])
   {
       // ...
   }
   Func(arr);
   ```
2. The function parameter is a array of pointers :

   ```
   bool *arr[10];
   for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
       arr[i] = new bool[10];
   void Func(bool *a[10])
   {
       // ...
   }
   Func(arr);
   ```
3. The function parameters is as `pointer` to `pointer` :

   ```
   bool **arr;
   arr = new bool *[10];
   for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
       arr[i] = new bool[10];
   void Func(bool **a)
   {
       // ...
   }
   Func(arr);
   ```